# Unable to install Kik on android

Tags: applications, google-play-store, kik-messenger

I'm trying to install the kik app from the google play store. I click on the install button and it flashes "pending" but then immediately shows the install button again. I cannot install the app because it won't go beyond this. It just keeps showing the install button. I'm using an Samsung S8+ with android version 9. How do I fix? Thank you.

Comment: See this https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/7513003